# SetEnvIfNoCase for CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

How to set this line

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI get_file\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

to codeigniter htaccess, if my class is download_file and method is index()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's not correct syntax.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifnocase) Use this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI get_file\.php$ no-gzip=dont-vary
```

Comment: hmmm.. I know it :) but how to set it to CI, when there is no such a file, there is only a class and method?

Comment: Place that in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file

Comment: you mean application/controllers/ ?

Comment: Wherever your main .htaccess is at present.